# With flutter, how to add a Provider later to the application?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a flutter application which uses a MultiProvider widget at the root of the widgets tree.
The problem is, I need to add a ChangeNotifierProvider to the MultiProvider widget, but later because I can't create it at the beginning (well I could but it makes more sense to do it later *).
How am I supposed to do?

(* for more details about why I would like to create the ChangeNotifierProvider later: The associated ChangeNotifier represents a bluetooth connection that will not be available at the start of the application.)

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but Providers (registered with MultiProvider) by default are lazily created - i.e. `create:` isn't called until the provider is read for the first time. There's a small mention in the docs here, just after the first code block: https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Provider-class.html

Answer (score 0):

In these situations I create Provider with object which have some initial values and later I change initial values to actual.